# Working with Fragment layout

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, android-framelayout

I'm new in android programming, I have created a navigation drawer activity and I have added swipe to refresh with Recycler view, but I get it like that when I run the app below was my output.

[image]

This is my MainActivity.Java file :

```
public class KworldActivity extends AppCompatActivity
implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
NavigationView navigationView=null;
Toolbar toolbar=null;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_kworld);

    RssMainFragment fragment=new RssMainFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction 
    fragmentTransaction=getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
    fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container,fragment);
    fragmentTransaction.commit();

    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

    DrawerLayout drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
    this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, 
    R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
    drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
    toggle.syncState();

    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) 
    findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
}
```

This my Fragment.Java file :

```
public class RssMainFragment extends Fragment {
RecyclerView recyclerView;
public RssMainFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}


@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view =inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_rss_main, container, 
false);
    return view;
}

}
```

This is my fragment.xml:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.karary.university.RssMainFragment">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    tools:context="com.karary.university.RSS.Details"
    tools:showIn="@layout/fragment_rss_main">


    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerview"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

This is my fragment_container.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout 
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="com.karary.university.KworldActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</FrameLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You not defined **layout_behavior** in your FrameLayout

In Coordinator layout we need to define how the child view should behave

So below AppBarLayout you have a FrameLayout that acting as child view

So in that FrameLayout  you should define

```
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
```

**here is the edited code.**
i tested this one and it's working. let me know if you still getting problem

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<FrameLayout
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
</FrameLayout>
```

fragment xml

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/swipe_container"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">


<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerview"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: How I put recycler view in side my fragment without making the recyclerview take the whole activity?